# Oracle multiple fields in Select IN Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select * FROM STUDENT 
WHERE (student.course, student.major) IN (SELECT schedule.course, schedule.major 
FROM schedule)
```

What if i have to provide static values, what would be the query like?  Because I am passing the SQL from a middle layer based on input parameters.

Edit: I am looking to search based on multiple sets of values.  For ex.

```
Select * FROM STUDENT 
WHERE (student.course, student.major) IN 
(('MBA', 'Computers'), ('BA', 'Computers'))
```

Comment: What static values, exactly, are you trying to handle?  Are you trying to send multiple values for a single column (i.e. an array of majors)?  Or are you trying to send static values for multiple columns (i.e. a course and a major)?

Comment: You are looking to replace `(SELECT schedule.course, schedule.major 
FROM schedule)` with a static/parameter list?

Comment: Cade, yes, I am looking to replace with the static parameter list (pass 1 or more sets of data).

Comment: @priceline - OK.  And what is the "middle layer" that you are passing the data from?

Comment: Your edit appears to be a query that should work just fine. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can use this:

```
Select * FROM STUDENT 
WHERE (student.course, student.major) 
IN (SELECT 'MBA', 'Computers' from DUAL 
    union SELECT 'BA', 'Computers' from DUAL);
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean (or am I misunderstanding something about hardcoding?):

```
select * from student
 where course = 'DB101'
   and major = 'MyMajor'
```